# Content not going into columns - What's wrong with my html code?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to load this content on a blog post but it will not go side by side in the columns. Instead it comes one above the other.
Please could you advise on my coding -

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
<div class="col-md-4"><img src="/x/blog/PET%20Measuring.jpg" alt="Quality Control of PET, by Richmond Containers" title="Quality Control of PET at example" style="margin-right: 0px;" gt="" div="" />
<div class="col-md-8">
<p><br />Take a look at our range of recycled Products <a href="https://www.example.com/product/" title="Richmond PCR Products | example.com" target="_blank">here</a>.<br /><br />Want to see all PET products? <a href="https://www.example.com/product/search" title="Example Products | example.com" target="_blank">Click here</a>.<br /><br /></p>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you closed all div tags?

Comment: Is the CSS for `row` and `col-` classes loaded?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you forgot to close the div tag on your col-md-4.

Try replacing line 2 with:

```
<div class="col-md-4"><img src="/x/blog/PET%20Measuring.jpg"  alt="Quality Control of PET, by Richmond Containers" title="Quality Control of PET at example" style="margin-right: 0px;" gt=""></div>
```

Comment: Legend - Thank You. ALl working now - https://www.richmondcontainers.com/demystifying-petg-how-does-it-differ-from-pet-and-can-you-recycle-it-

Comment: No problem! :))

Comment: This answer is insufficient. You need to close all `<div>` elements.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you have missed closing the `col-md-4` `div` tag before starting the `col-md-8` `div` tag, try this

```
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <div class="col-md-4"><img src="/x/blog/PET%20Measuring.jpg" alt="Quality Control of PET, by Richmond Containers"
      title="Quality Control of PET at example" style="margin-right: 0px;" gt="" div="" />
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-8">
    <p><br />Take a look at our range of recycled Products <a href="https://www.example.com/product/"
        title="Richmond PCR Products | example.com" target="_blank">here</a>.<br /><br />Want to see all PET products?
      <a href="https://www.example.com/product/search" title="Example Products | example.com" target="_blank">Click
        here</a>.<br /><br />
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also closed the `col-md-8` `div` tag, and the `row` `div` tag.